# SEO для доменов в разных зонах

Tags: seo, хостинг

Есть сайт, его адрес [example.com](http://example.com). Теперь я зарегистрировал домен [example.ru](http://example.ru).

Любой пользователь, заходя на эти домены, обращается к одному и тому же серверу. Но тогда возникает проблема: в поисковых системах контент сайта будет дублироваться (один для зоны com, другой - для ru) - это, видимо, не очень хорошо.

Хотел бы получить совет: как вообще ПРАВИЛЬНО используют два таких домена? С какой целью?

Answer (score 1):

Ну наверное правильно делать редирект на основной и в сети продвигать его. Продвигать два одинаковых сайта под разными доменами - точно плохо.

Answer (score 1):

Пример - Гугл, у них тоже много доменов. Вообще, поисковые системы видят адреса с www и без www как разные, а тут еще разные домены. Поэтому нужен и редирект, и дополнительно в файле [robots.txt](http://robots.txt) и в панелях для веб-мастеров ПС надо указывать основной хост, чтобы ПС видели сайт так, как Вы хотите. Да в помощи ПС для веб-мастеров это все описано.